# DebugDiag memory dump analysis to identify cause of an IIS crash?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, iis, serialization, debugdiag

We have a number of WCF services hosted in IIS with a WPF front end.
Occasionally IIS will crash, with what looks to be a serialisation error but unsure where or what object is failing. We suspect its the serialisation of an entity framework object collection (with navigation properties etc), but the object in question serialises fine when tested internally. IIS crashes maybe once/twice a day onsite. The object in question is used heavily by end users, which leads me to believe if this is a genuine serialisation fault then we would see serialisation over WCF fail every time? Could it be failing only on certain occasions, or could something else be causing IIS to crash like this? We're finding this difficult to track down.

There is an entry in the event log from source 'WAS'

> A process serving application pool 'xxx' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
>   process ID was '1016'. The data field contains the error number.

This is the memory dump/ stack trace captured using DebugDiag tool.

> The following threads in
>   w3wp__appPoolName__PID__2932__Date__09_29_2016__Time_01_00_26PM__964__Ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess.dmp are calling the TerminateProcess function to kill the process
>
> ( 39 )
>
> 2,13% of threads blocked (1 threads)
>
> Please look at the callstack of the thread to see what it is doing
>   which is ending up in a call to TerminateProcess function
>
> Thread 39 - System ID 4564
>
> Entry point   clr!GetPrivateContextsPerfCounters+16f00  Create time
>   29.09.2016 12:59:25  Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:08.125  Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
>
> This thread is calling the TerminateProcess function to kill the
>   process
>
> The thread has evidence of .net exceptions on the stack. Check the
>   Previous .NET Exceptions Report (Exceptions in all .NET Thread Stacks)
>   to view more details of the associated exception
>
> .NET Call Stack
>
> [[FaultingExceptionFrame]] 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Xml.XmlBaseWriter.WriteStartElement(System.String,
>   System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString)+3b 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator.WriteStartElement(System.String,
>   System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString)+23 
>   DynamicClass.**Write*EntityName*ToXml**(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract)+14b9 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext)+31 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator, System.Object,
>   Boolean, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.Type)+eb 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.Type, Int32,
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.Type)+309 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Int32,
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle)+247897 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)+6f 
>   DynamicClass.WriteObjectListToXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract)+1aa 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext)+41 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)+6f 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)+6f 
>   DynamicClass.WriteKeyValueOfstringObjectListtGI2ndrTToXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract)+176 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext)+31 
>   DynamicClass.WriteObjectsRemovedFromCollectionPropertiesToXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract)+1a1 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext)+41 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)+6f 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)+6f 
>   DynamicClass.WriteEntityChangeTrackerToXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract)+31a 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext)+31 
>   System_Runtime_Serialization_ni!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator,
>   System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle)+6f...

... serialisation continues like this, followed by...

> ...System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext,
>   Boolean, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)+7d7 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext,
>   System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)+1ff 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult)+db
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)+32
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)+19e
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel+TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(System.IAsyncResult)+11d
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)+32
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)+19e
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource+ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(System.Object)+82
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(System.Object)+170
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(System.Object,
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)+fd 
>   System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError,
>   Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)+bd5 
>   System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+40 
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+96  [[GCFrame]] 
>   [[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]  [[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
>   [[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]

Full Stack Trace

> System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression.Make(System.Object,
>   System.Type)+69 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression)+12d  0x000000dc`6cf0c5d0 
>   clr!GetMetaDataPublicInterfaceFromInternal+3c494 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)+ae
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator+ContainsTranslator.TranslateContains(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)+46 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)+d3 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression)+132 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)+ae
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression)+7e 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator+OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression ByRef,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpressionBinding ByRef,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpression ByRef)+eb 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator+OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)+3d 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)+d3 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)+ae
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator+SelectTranslator.Translate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)+65 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)+d3 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()+a2
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(System.Nullable`1)+128
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass3[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]].<GetResults>b__2()+27 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]](System.Func`1,
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy, Boolean,
>   Boolean)+110  [[StubHelperFrame]] 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass3[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]].<GetResults>b__1()+ef 
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]](System.Func`1)+3b 
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1)+170
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]].<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()+b
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]].MoveNext()+32 
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)+218
>   System_Core_ni!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]+50
>   **Repository.MethodName**(System.Collections.Generic.List1)+1626
>   **ServiceName.MethodName**(System.Collections.Generic.List`1)+18
>   DynamicClass.SyncInvoke**MethodName**(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Object[])+7a 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Object[] ByRef)+6a4 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc
>   ByRef)+505 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc
>   ByRef)+110 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc
>   ByRef)+17b 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean)+17e
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext,
>   Boolean, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)+7d7 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext,
>   System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)+1ff 
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult)+db
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)+32
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)+19e
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel+TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(System.IAsyncResult)+11d
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)+32
>   System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)+19e
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource+ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(System.Object)+82
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(System.Object)+170
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(System.Object,
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs)+fd 
>   System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError,
>   Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)+bd5 
>   System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+40 
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+96  [[GCFrame]] 
>   [[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]  [[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
>   [[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]

Could too much data also cause this? Thank you,

Comment: What code is actually throwing this error? Do you use lazy loading in EF?

Comment: No, we don't use lazy loading, using code first

Comment: A massive object graph being serialized doesn't sound good. Nothing really comes to mind except perhaps use a different serializer.